# c#Taking the value entered in textbox and performing a calc based on which 2 Radio Buttons are checked and displaying the result in the label

Tags: c#, radio-button

I'm just starting off with C# and I've been stuck trying to understand what I'm doing wrong for a couple of hours. I've tried so many different variations with no success so I wouldn't be surprised if I'm completely off at this point. What I'm trying to do is suppose to allow the user to enter a value then click one radio button in each of the groups. So the user is expected to make a selection in the group 1 radio buttons first which will be the original type of measurement that is being entered into the textbox. Then select from the group 2 radio buttons what they would like to convert the value entered into the textbox to (for ex. in. to cm.) and after selecting 1 radio button from each group. Click the convert button which then should show the conversion in the output label.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const double INCHEStoCM = 2.54;
    const double INCHEStoM = 0.0254;
    const double FEETtoCM = 30.48;
    const double FEETtoM = 0.3048;
                                  


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //to exit
        {
        DialogResult respExit;
        respExit = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to exit?", "Distance Converter", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
         if(respExit==DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                this.Close();

            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxNumber.Clear();
        labelOutput.Text = "";
        textBoxNumber.Focus();
    }

    private void buttonConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double inNumber = 0, outMetricValue = 0;
     
        try // check if data is a number
        {
            inNumber = double.Parse(Text);
            outMetricValue = double.Parse(Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data entered must be a number", "Distance Converter");
            buttonReset.PerformClick();
            return;
        }

       
        // check number is > 0; <0 is error
        if(inNumber<0)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Value entered must be >0", "Distance Converter App");
            buttonReset.PerformClick();
            return;
        }

        if (radioButtonInches.Checked && radioButtonCm.Checked)
        {
            outMetricValue = inNumber * INCHEStoCM;
            labelOutput.Text = outMetricValue.ToString("n");
         }

    }

  
   
  
}
```

}

Comment: There are numerous issues you may have. For starters… put a breakpoint on the line… `inNumber = double.Parse(Text);` … If you do, you will see that `Text` does not contain what you think it does. You should step through the code using the debugger. Have you done this? If you are not familiar with the VS debugger, I suggest you peruse… [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) … the debugger is helpful for seeing what your code is doing or in this case not doing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. Sounds worst than I thought. I will check out the Microsoft link you included. Would it make sense to start from scratch at this point? Considering how many issues?

Comment: _”Start from scratch”_ … No. What you have is enough. You are doing fine. You will certainly need to rethink what you are wanting to do with the “radio” buttons. Unless the “radio” buttons are in different controls, then ONLY ONE (1) can be “checked” at any one time. If you check one, the other will become “un-Checked.” So, your current `if` condition will never be `true` because of this. But start simple and get a valid number from the "text box" first.

Comment: I suggest you use `decimals` instead of `doubles` and look up the `decimal.TryParse` method. This method will help you “validate” the “number” the user types into the text box. Once you “know” you have a valid number, then move on to the conversion. Here you want to check which radio button is “checked” since only one can be checked, and then apply the conversion depending on which radio button was “checked.” If you have problems, update your question.

Comment: Lastly, FYI… the reason the line… `inNumber = double.Parse(Text);` … is not returning what you expect is that the property `Text` is miss what “text” are you wanting… without this identifier, it will use is parents object. In this case, most likely the form itself, so it is really using… `this.Text`. In your case, you want to get the “text” from the `TextBox`. So, you want… `inNumber = double.Parse(textBoxNumber.Text);`. This works but a “TryParse` is a better approach.

Comment: Got it on all the suggestions above. Thank you. One thing I do want to clarify is the radio buttons are grouped separately. So the user is expected to make a selection in the group 1 radio buttons which will hold the original type of measurement that is being entered into the textbox. Then select from the group 2 radio buttons what they would like to convert the value entered into the textbox to and after selecting 1 radio button from each group. Click the convert button which then should show the conversion in the output label.  My apologies I should have included that with my question.

Comment: Yea I was afraid I was missing something on the radio buttons. I jumped the gun on the radio buttons, my bad, sorry.